# Is there a difference in the Promise type returned by an ordinary function and an async function?

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, q

Let's say I have a Typescript project with the following (latest) packages:

- q@1.5.0
- typescript@2.5.2
- @types/q@1.0.5

Now let's say in my project I define a function that returns a Promise (as defined by Typescript's native ambient declarations):

```js
import * as q from "q";

function doSomethingElseAsync(): Promise<number> {
    return q.Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 5000);
    });
}
```

When compiling, Typescript complains with the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Q.Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'.
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
    Type '<U>(onFulfill?: ((value: number) => IWhenable<U>) | undefined, onReject?: ((error: any) => IWhena...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = number, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: number) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TR...'.
      Types of parameters 'onFulfill' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
        Type '((value: number) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '((value: number) => IWhenable<TResult1 | TResult2>) | undefined'.
          Type 'null' is not assignable to type '((value: number) => IWhenable<TResult1 | TResult2>) | undefined'.
```

For a while, I thought it was because Q Promises just weren't compatible with Typescript's native declarations. However, if I add the `async` keyword to the function definition, the error disappears entirely.

I'm rather mystified by this behavior. Is this a bug in Typescript, Q, or the Q typings? Or is this some esoteric but expected behavior of the compiler?

Comment: possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689713/es6-promise-typescript-and-the-bluebird-promise basically... a q promise isn't a native promise. just like a bluebird promise isn't a native promise.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a native promise or not so long as it fits the interface Typescript is expecting. Both Q and Bluebird promises work well enough in practice.

Comment: right, but more importantly, do they match the interface? i don't think they do.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. I swapped the return type of the async function to `q.Promise` and got a compiler error saying "it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value." This makes sense, because `q.Promise` isn't a constructor you call with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that adding the `async` keyword to your function causes Javascript to wrap the return value of that function in a native `Promise` so that whether the function returns a promise or a value, the result will be a promise that can be `await`ed.

For example, it would do something like this:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => doSomethingElseAsync())
```

Without the `async` keyword, you're returning a `q` promise, which is not an instance of a native `Promise`, so you're getting a type error for it.

I believe it would work fine like this as well (with the `q` removed):

```
function doSomethingElseAsync(): Promise<number> {
    return Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 5000);
    });
}
```

Or if your environment doesn't include the native `Promise` class, perhaps changing the return type might work, like this:

```
function doSomethingElseAsync(): q.Promise<number> {
    return q.Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the return value in a native promise sounds more like an implementation detail of async/await. Once the JavaScript is output, types don't factor in anymore.

Removing Q wouldn't work if my target is ES5, which doesn't implement native promises. That's why I'm using an external implementation like Q.

Comment: I updated the answer with a potential ES5 solution as well if you don't have Promises available natively

Comment: Also, yes, sorry, the wrapping was more a thought on potentially how async/await works vs. how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like the problem is simply that Q promises are incompatible with async/await.**

I tried swapping the return type of the async fuction from the native `Promise` to `q.Promise`. The compiler now gives me this error:

```
Type '<T>(resolver: (resolve: (val?: T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined) => void, reject: (reason?: any) =>...' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.
  Type '<T>(resolver: (resolve: (val?: T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined) => void, reject: (reason?: any) =>...' provides no match for the signature 'new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): PromiseLike<T>'.
```

It says the return type "is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value." This makes sense, because `q.Promise` isn't a constructor function you can call with `new`. In contrast, other promise implementations, such as Bluebird, do have compatible constructor functions.